# How can I use the if and else to do the multiple determination in this case? if and else cannot work well

Tags: perl

We need to make a program to analyse a DNA sequence with Perl. Mine is the last task: to analyse the result file from the others.

This is a column of numbers which are sorted from smallest to biggest. [The result file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH0Dx.png)

I have three parameters get from the STDIN. They are `$from`, `$to`, and `$intervals`. For example

```
1000 5000 200
```

In this case, the range 1000 .. 5000 is divided into 20 bins. Each bin's size is 200. The program should scan the data file and find whether the number is in the current bin. If it is in this bin, then calculate it and go to the next line until the number is out of this bin; then go to the next bin. If it is not in the current bin, then go to the next bin and do nothing about it.

The final result should be look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMKQ4.png)

Here is my script about this part. My questions are in the script.

```perl
while ( defined( my $m_z_value = <$ff> ) ) {

    $m_z_value =~ s/^\s+//;           # /

  GOD:
    chomp $m_z_value;

    if ( $tmp_to <= $to and $m_z_value <= $to ) {    # limit the bin in the range

        if ( $m_z_value >> $tmp_to ) {               # Here if I don't use double ">", the program will just ignore it. Even I use double ">",sometime it still don't work, I don't know why?
            ++$bin_number;
            print "$bin_number\t\t $tmp_from\t $tmp_to\t 0\t\t -\n";
            $tmp_from = $tmp_from + $intervals;
            $tmp_to   = $tmp_to + $intervals;
            goto GOD;                                # if the value is in the main range but out of the bin, move to the next bin and test it again
        }
        else {
            if ( $m_z_value < $from ) {
                goto MIRACLE;                        # if the value is before the range, go to next line
            }
            else {
                if ( $m_z_value == $from ) {         # similar problem, if I don't use double "=", in this part, the program will define the value of $m_z_value the same as $from
                    $mass       = $mass + $m_z_value;
                    $whole_mass = $whole_mass + $m_z_value;
                    ++$bin_pepnumber;
                    ++$whole_pepnumber;

                    print "$bin_number\t\t $tmp_from\t $tmp_to\t $bin_pepnumber\t\t $mass/$bin_pepnumber\n";
                }
                else {
                    if ( $m_z_value >= $tmp_from and $m_z_value <= $tmp_to ) {
                        $mass       = $mass + $m_z_value;
                        $whole_mass = $whole_mass + $m_z_value;
                        ++$bin_pepnumber;
                        ++$whole_pepnumber;
                    }
                    else {
                        if ( $m_z_value > $tmp_to ) {
                            print "$bin_number\t\t $tmp_from\t $tmp_to\t $bin_pepnumber\t\t $mass/$bin_pepnumber\n";
                            ++$bin_number;
                            $mass          = $m_z_value;
                            $whole_mass    = $whole_mass + $m_z_value;
                            $bin_pepnumber = 0;
                            ++$whole_pepnumber;
                            $tmp_from = $tmp_from + $intervals;
                            $tmp_to   = $tmp_to + $intervals;
                            goto GOD;    #if the m/z value is bigger than the range, go to next bin and test it again
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      MIRACLE:
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having? I'm not going to scan 50 lines of code for comments---please spell out your specific problem up front. By the way, `>>` is a bit shift operator, not an enhanced form of greater than.

Comment: FYI you can use `next` instead of `goto MIRACLE`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The problems is in the script. 1 the second "if", why should I use double ">" to make it work? one ">" will be ignored.  2 4th "if", similar problem, double "=". 3 MOST IMPORTANT problem. In the result picture, the range 240~260, I use the debug software, the $m_z_value at that time is 245.1488, the $tmp_to is 260, but the program run the script in if ($m_z_value >> $tmp_to){}. And other results are all good. I thought it was a mistake, but I've run it many times, same results come out...It drives me crazy...@MattJacob

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33790662/edit) the original post to include that information/clarify the problem. Also, because of the image, the post is not currently a good [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nobody is going to retype a column of floating-point numbers to reproduce your issue so that they can help you. Please include that as text.

Comment: Please avoid images wherever possible. Code and data should be posted *within* the question so that we can easily replicate your problem

Comment: `GOD` and `MIRACLE` may make you laugh, but they don't help anyone to understand your program. If you aren't taking this seriously then you should quit the course, but please don't ask for help when you have written comedy

Comment: *Well done* for prefixing `++` in `++$bin_number` etc. Most people just know the name of the C++ language and wrongly put it afterwards without thinking

Comment: @Borodin It makes no difference in this case whether it's `++$i` or `$i++`.

Comment: @MattJacob: Writing bad code because it does the same thing as good code isn't a good guideline. It rarely makes any difference with modern compilers if the value of the increment is unused, but that is not the point. Writing `C++` means *increment C but return me C's previous value*. That's almost *never* what is intended. "Increment C" looks like `++C`. It is always easier to read if the verb precedes the object. The name of the language has a lot to answer for

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the bin number is easy to calculate directly:

```
$bin_number = int (($m_z_value - $from) / $intervals);
```

Next thing, perl has arrays for representing things like bins:

```
++$bin_pep_number[$bin_number];
$mass[$bin_number] += $m_z_value;
```

Putting it all together:

```
my @bin_pep_number;
my @mass;
my $bin_number;
while(defined(my $m_z_value = <$ff>)) {
    $m_z_value =~ s/^\s+//;
    chomp $m_z_value;

    $bin_number = int (($m_z_value - $from) / $intervals);
    ++$bin_pep_number[$bin_number];
    $mass[$bin_number] += $m_z_value;
    }

$bin_number = 0;
for (my $tmp_from=$from; $tmp_from<$to; $tmp_from+=$intervals) {
    my $tmp_to = $tmp_from + $intervals;
    print "$bin_number\t\t";
    print "$tmp_from\t";
    print "$tmp_to\t";
    print "$bin_pepnumber[$bin_number]\t\t";
    print "$mass[$bin_number]/$bin_pepnumber[$bin_number]" if $bin_pep_number[$bin_number];
    print "\n";
    ++$bin_number;
    }
```

Comment: Nice tight code, but `while ( defined( my $m_z_value = <$ff> ) )` is commonly written `while ( my $m_z_value = <$ff> )`

Comment: @Borodin Won't that fail if a zero m_z_value comes in?

Comment: No. Perl adds the `defined` for you in this case. Try running `perl -MO=Deparse -e'print $line while $line = <>'`